# Web Api Post Complex-Object with Generic List-Property, Count 0

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I have some pretty basic HttpClient code that comes down to this:

```
var criteria = new Criteria() { Name = "TestName" };
criteria.listProperty.Add(new ComplexObject<int>("value", true));
httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("api/ctl/myAction", criteria)
```

The controller looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage myAction([FromBody]Criteria criteria)
{
    return DoSomethingWithIt(criteria);
}
```

The thing is, I put a break point on my `PostAsJsonAsync`, and my criteria object has the name "TestName", and its listProperty has one item with "value" and true properties.  All is as it should be.

But the break point on the controller shows criteria to have Count 0, while it still shows the criteria object's name to be "TestName."  I then tried this:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage myAction(Object criteria)
{
    var jsonString = model.ToString();
}
```

And jsonString has everything, including the complex property with "value" and true properties.

My Criteria and ComplexObject objects are like so:

```
public class SearchCriteria
{
    public List<ComplexObject> listProperty { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ComplexObject<T> : ComplexObject
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public List<T> Choices { get; private set; }

    public ComplexObject<T>(string complexName, bool isRequired, List<T> choices = null)
    {
        this.ComplexName = complexName;
        this.IsRequired = isRequired;
        this.Choices = choices;
    }
}

public abstract class ComplexObject
{
    public string ComplexName { get; protected set; }
    public bool IsRequired { get; protected set; }
}
```

P.S.: I have tried both controllers with and without [FromBody].

Answer (score 1):

The answer is, as you might expect, that Generic types are lost when crossing HTTP or deserialized to JSON.  In order to make this work, I had to write a custom parser (Deserializer) on my abstract ComplexObject, and an iterator in the SearchCriteria to call the parser for each listProperty.

In the end, this was an elegant answer to my Web API usage between c# projects that shared my Model namespace(s).  But it was far more complex than necessary for usage amongst my MVC project(s) using razor and/or angularjs.

If you are using generics in Web API and having issues, my recommendation is to re-evaluate what part of your application to be pretty.  You can either have a pretty backend that can easily pass around generics, or a clean frontend that will require more basic backend code to serialize across http.